# Sequelize Postgres Transaction Issue

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table profiles with composite unique key on profileId and provider fields. I am using model to create records in profiles table and the code is as follows

```
async function createUserProfile(userProfile){
   let transaction;
   try{
      transaction = await sequelize.transaction();
      const hyperProfile = await UserHyperProfiles.create(userProfile, {transaction:transaction});
      console.log("profile cretaed");
      transaction.commit();
   }catch(error){
     if(transaction){
       transaction.rollback()
     }
     console.log(error);
   }
}
```

with above code even I am not having any record it gives me unique constraint error

```
  SequelizeUniqueConstraintError : Key (provider, profileid)=(google, f123) already exists.
```

but when i remove transaction from create call it works fine.
Is there something I am missing?.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question you are missing `await` before `transaction.commit` & `transaction.rollback`.

Comment: Do you really have `(google, f123)` in postgres db ?

Comment: @RatulSharker same result with having await in front of transaction.commit() and transaction.rollback()

Comment: (google, 123) are just example values

Comment: do they exists prior running the insertion ?